# XAML binding multiple properties in label content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have two properties, Related_Id and PageNumber. I want to bind these two values to a single label.

XAML code

```
<StackPanel>
    <sdk:Label x:Name="RelatedItemIdLabel"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Content="{Binding CreateMessage.RelatedId}" />
</StackPanel>
```

current output: **Related_Id**

Desired output: **Related_Id/ PageNumber**

Could anyone help me to find a solution..

Thanks..

Comment: Use a MultiBinding.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541896/concatenate-strings-instead-of-using-a-stack-of-textblocks)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399178/stringformat-and-multibinding-with-label for the correct solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <Label x:Name="RelatedItemIdLabel"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label.Content>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0}/{1}">
                <Binding Path="" /> //insert field 1
                <Binding Path="" /> //insert field 2
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Content>
    </Label>
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. but I am getting the following error:
 The name "MultiBinding" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007

Comment: well one more thing you can do is to make a read only property in which you concatenate Related_Id and PageNumber and then you can bind that to your label's content. Like this
' public string IDandPage
        {
            get
            {
                return RelatedId + "/" + PageNumber;
            }
        } '

Answer (score -1):

This is the code you're looking for :

```
<StackPanel>
    <sdk:Label x:Name="RelatedItemIdLabel"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">    
    <sdk:Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0}, {1}">
            <Binding Path="{Binding CreateMessage.RelatedId}"/>
            <Binding Path="{Binding CreateMessage.PageNumber}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </sdk:Label.Content>    
    </sdk:Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: thanks for your help.. but I am getting the following error:
 The name "MultiBinding" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007

Comment: @NanduPH: Is it working now? The above code works fine at my end.